# Someone sent 0 ETH to my contract and got 134100 tokens

Tags: tokens, erc-20

we have just finished a phase of our ICO and we were looking among the transactions. Someone managed to send 0 ETH to our contract and in return got 130 000 tokens. How did he do that and how vulnerable is our system?

This is the holder with our tokens:
https://etherscan.io/token/0x9a9ae6884c65725c8f5378dbb6d3900bff36da53?a=0x2bf6064d8fdb75af047d3db4743d436adb326312

These are his transactions. He seems to have created his own contract and he has done the same to someone else:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x2bf6064d8fdb75af047d3db4743d436adb326312

Please help

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It wasnt mint tokens function because I am the one who does the minting. This transaction I do not recognize. Furthermore, the address that got the token appears to have sent 0 ETH towards the contract. I do not fully understand what is going on and I am unable to explain very well. Maybe this person managed to gain access to my contract owner private key?

Comment: It seems like the use of the `mintTokens` is used somewhere that is external from the contract itself. When I look at the token contracts transactions (https://etherscan.io/address/0x9a9ae6884c65725c8f5378dbb6d3900bff36da53), I don't see any ether flowing through...so where is ETH being sent and what is the scenario that is calling the `mintTokens` function? From an outside perspective, it seems like the fault is somewhere in centralized code.

Comment: If you are `0x03fdb8a96b10872bcd7303fd00a6cb59d91382b6` is possible that someone got access to your private key, but I can say for certain that it was this address, the contract owner, who initiated the function call. You can see that [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x559e429a2ca57d298203da1447d74e3699370d65023f33cebe757b2b4ca57f55). They called the `mintTokens` function with `0x2bf6064d8fdb75af047d3db4743d436adb326312` as the recieving address, and `0x1c65935853bfead00000 == 134100000000000000000000` as the amount of tokens.

Answer (score 12):

It wasn't just just "someone"... it was the [contract creator](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x559e429a2ca57d298203da1447d74e3699370d65023f33cebe757b2b4ca57f55) who made the transaction, and there is a function called `mintTokens` which allows them to exactly do this.

```
/**
 *  Allows owner to create tokens without ETH
 */
function mintTokens(address _address, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner isUnderHardCap
{
    if(disown == 1) revert();

    if (amount + tokenTotalSupply > hardcap) revert();
    if (amount < 1) revert();

    //add tokens to balance
    balances[_address] = balances[_address] + amount;

    //increase total tokens
    tokenTotalSupply = tokenTotalSupply.add(amount);
    Transfer(this, _address, amount);
    noContributors++;
}
```

Additionally, it looks like `if (amount + tokenTotalSupply > hardcap) revert();` is vulnerable to an overflow attack.